# C# Import from .NET DLL

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, dllimport

How do I import methods from a .NET DLL to call from my C# code?  I've tried both the `[DllImport...]` approach and using reflection with Assembly.  I'm very inexperienced at .NET so apologies if this is a very basic question.  My goal is to call `LZ4Decompressor32().Decompress(byte[])`.

Reflector shows `LZ4Decompressor32` as being a derived type from the base type `ILZ4Decompressor`.  All of this resides under `Exec` which I guess is the parent namespace?

Screenshot: http://s0.uploads.im/KEqXk.jpg

I expect I'm just messing up the namespace or type path but I've tried every combination I can think of.

FYI this is an old CTF challenge that I'm doing to learn.  The full challenge extracts the next stage from its resource section then calls the `LZ4Decompressor32().Decompress()` method on the resource data.

```
ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager(Name, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
byte[] compressed = (byte[]) manager.GetObject("data");
return new LZ4Decompressor32().Decompress(compressed);
```

Edit: For more info, when debugging and breaking on `Assembly.LoadFrom(...)` I get the following error:

*Could not load file or assembly 'file:///[dll path]' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.*

I ran the DLL through Dependency Walker and the only complaint was MSJAVA.DLL, which Dependency Walker explained (http://dependencywalker.com/faq.html).

Comment: Just add a project reference to the assembly and the appropriate `using namespace`

Comment: `DllImport` is for unmanaged code.

Comment: Based on your post and other comments it seems there is some lack of clarity as to which type of DLL you are working with.  There are three types: Win32, COM, and .NET.  If you don't know which type you're working with there's going to be problems!  Please location ildasm.exe on your machine, run it, and try to open the DLL in question.  If it opens it's a .NET DLL.  If it doesn't, try running `RegSvr32.exe <DLL name>`.  If this works it's a COM DLL.  Otherwise it's probably a Win32 DLL.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps.

1. Open the project for your main program (your web project or your exe project ) in Visual Studio.
2. Locate the "Solution Explorer" pane
3. Right click on the "References" node and choose "Add Reference"
4. Click "Browse"
5. Select the DLL you wish to "import" and click OK

Congratulations, you have now "imported" all the non-internal, non-private classes and methods in your DLL.

Just instantiate and use.

Comment: This is another approach I forgot to mention but via Project > Add Reference... I suspect it's the same path.  The error was `A reference to <dll path> could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.`


Googled this error, I found that the DLL needed to be registered.  However, when I tried to register it with regsrv32, I received `<dll path> is not an executable file and no registration helper is registered for this file type.`

From file: `PE32 executable for MS Windows (DLL) (console) Intel 80386 32-bit Mono/.Net assembly`

Comment: More googling yielded the advice to use RegAsm, which gave this error:  `RegAsm : error RA0000 : Failed to load '<dll path>' because it is not a valid .NET assembly`.  I've tried all the workarounds for I've found for tihs problem (run as Administrator, check file permissions, try a different /tlb path, etc) but still no luck.  Looks like registering the DLL is still my blocker.

Comment: @MikeJones You're probably on the wrong track trying to register the DLL.  Regsvr32 and regasm are used to register COM objects but LZ4Sharp doesn't appear to be a COM object.  Regsvr32 expects to LoadLibrary a native code DLL which is why you get the "not an executable file" error - to a program expecting native code a managed assembly doesn't look valid.  [Regasm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx)  expects to load a managed assembly containing a COM object including COM specific metadata.  You're getting "not a valid .NET assembly" because there's no COM metatdata.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the flag by importing the source from the LZ4Sharp project.  My hope was to learn something about reflection and namespace / class paths, but I guess I can experiment with that on my own.  Thanks for the suggestions, everyone; and thanks @Frank Boyne for the explanation about regsvr32 and regasm.